# React - translations per component

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, translation, create-react-app, i18next

I'm using create-react-app for my React application and I'm currently trying to figure out translations.

Right now I have one big JSON file per locale and each locale file includes translations for all components - which is not ideal and I would like to have separate translation files for each component.

So the structure of locales will look like this:
ComponentA
- locales
  - en.json
  - sk.json

ComponentB
- locales
  - en.json
  - sk.json

What is the best way to achieve this? Which modules should I use to achieve this?

I do not want to include these locale files into build because we will support 10 languages so the bundle size will be too big.

Comment: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next using i18next namepaces per component

Comment: @jamuhl Thank you - yes this will work fine. However when loading namespaces via XHR, then locale files needs to be under public directory in my app. I would rather keep them next to component so it's easy to navigate.

Comment: @jamuhl And also another issue is that one page can easily have 100 components. And in this case 100 requests will be fired to load all locales so I think this is not a good thing.

Comment: @PaloDelinčák I think the count of requests is irrelevant because of the multiplexing in http/2

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to answer my own question. After research I figured out that my use-case is rare and I decided to do some locale pre-processing to achieve desired functionality.

I'm running default config of `create-react-app` together with `react-i18next` and my file structure looks like this:

```js
src
  - Component A
    - locales
      - en.json
      - sk.json
  - Component B
    - locales
      - en.json
```

Here are settings for the `react-i18next` module:

```js
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use('en')
  .use(reactI18nextModule)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: false,
    backend: {
      loadPath: function() {
        return `${config.BASE_URL}locales/{{lng}}.json`;
      }
    },
    react: {
      wait: true
    }
  });
```

Since I'm using default config of `create-react-app` then the locales are served from `public` folder in the app and build itself.

And now it gets tricky. Since the locale files are located in the component tree (and not in public folder) then we need to do some pre-processing of locales - basically we need to concat all JSON files and move them to the public folder.

Files for public folder are created on the fly using node task (`prepare-locales.js`) below:

```js
const jsonConcat = require('json-concat');
const minifyJson = require('minify-json');
const glob = require('glob');
const availableLocales = ['en', 'sk'];
const path = require('path');

module.exports.development = function() {
  availableLocales.forEach(locale => {
    glob(`./src/**/locales/${locale}.json`, {}, (err, globFiles) => {
      if (globFiles.length) {
        const file = `./public/locales/${locale}.json`;

        jsonConcat(
          {
            src: globFiles,
            dest: file
          },
          json => {
            minifyJson(file);
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });
};

module.exports.production = function() {
  glob('./build/static/js/main.*.js', {}, (err, globFiles) => {
    const files = require('source-map-explorer')(globFiles[0]).files;

    let localeFolders = [];
    Object.keys(files).forEach(fileName => {
      localeFolders.push(path.dirname(fileName).replace('./', ''));
    });
    localeFolders = [...new Set(localeFolders)];

    availableLocales.forEach(locale => {
      const localeFiles = localeFolders.map(
        lf => `./src/${lf}/locales/${locale}.json`
      );

      if (localeFiles.length) {
        const file = `./build/locales/${locale}.json`;

        jsonConcat(
          {
            src: localeFiles,
            dest: file
          },
          json => {
            minifyJson(file);
          }
        );
      }
    });
  });
};
```

For the development version I'm concating all JSON files which are found in the tree.

For the production version I'm using `source-map-explorer` and I'm concating only those locales which are used in the build.

Here is my simplified `package.json` with tasks required for this to work:

```js
{
  "devDependencies": {    
    "json-concat": "0.0.1",
    "minify-json": "^1.0.0",
    "npm-watch": "^0.4.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.1",
    "source-map-explorer": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {    
    "start": "react-scripts start & npm run prepare-locales:development:watch",
    "build:production": "react-scripts build && npm run prepare-locales:production",    
    "prepare-locales:development:watch": "npm-watch prepare-locales:development",
    "prepare-locales:development": "node -e 'require(\"./prepare-locales.js\").development()'",
    "prepare-locales:production": "node -e 'require(\"./prepare-locales.js\").production()'"
  },
  "watch": {
    "prepare-locales:development": {
      "patterns": "src/**/locales/",
      "extensions": "json"
    }
  }  
}
```

Maybe it's not the best solution but it works for my use-case and hopefully it will help someone with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Example of how to use i18next + React + Typescript with class definitions and separate files for translations https://gitlab.com/damjan89/i18next-typescript-example